# Nx missing dependencies on generated package.json

Tags: npm, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I've setup a basic publishable lib using `@nrwl/react`:

```
nx g @nrwl/react:lib my-new-lib --publishable --importPath=@myorg/my-new-lib
```

Then installed MUI in the monorepo root:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

And imported a MUI component:

```js
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

export function MyNewLib() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to MyNewLib!</h1>
      <Button>Hello</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyNewLib;
```

Finally I build the library using:

```
nx run my-new-lib:build
```

And this is the generated `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@myorg/my-new-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "module": "./index.js",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

MUI dependencies are not added to the generated `package.json`.

What I'm missing?

Here is a repo if you want to try it:

- https://github.com/oncet/nx-playground

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found a solution, adding this to my `nx.json`:

```
"pluginsConfig": {
    "@nrwl/js": {
      "analyzeSourceFiles": true
    }
  }
```

And this two options to my `build` target (I'm using `@nrwl/web:rollup`) in the `project.json`:

```
"updateBuildableProjectDepsInPackageJson": true,
"buildableProjectDepsInPackageJsonType": "dependencies"
```

Comment: I'm using `@nrwl/webpack`, so the `pluginsConfig` worked for me without adding the two build options.

Comment: In my case (@nrwl/webpack) this option helped - but without the two additional parameters in project.json not all of the dependencies were added into the build.

Answer (score 0):

@camilo's answer is great but there has been a few changes over the last year for NX.

This Medium article explains outlines what has changed,

https://dev.to/this-is-learning/manage-nx-library-dependencies-with-the-nxdependency-checks-eslint-rule-2lem

> Nx 16.4 introduces the @nx/dependency-checks ESLint rule to the @nx/linter package for verifying, adding, removing, and updating peerDependencies in the package.json source configuration file of buildable or publishable Nx library projects

Basically your `libs` need dependencies in their package.json **IF** you plan to publish them to npm (*the published package will lose context ox NX*).

If you don't then just change `@nx/dependency-checks` to not be an `error`.

```
{
  "files": ["*.json"],
  "parser": "jsonc-eslint-parser",
  "rules": {
    "@nx/dependency-checks": [
      "warn",
      {
        "ignoredFiles": ["{projectRoot}/vite.config.{js,ts,mjs,mts}"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Docs are here,

https://nx.dev/nx-api/eslint-plugin/documents/dependency-checks